# Meanjs:generator Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: MenusProvider <- Menus

Tags: node.js, menu, angular-ui-router, meanjs, yo

i have created new module using below command

```
$ yo meanjs:crud-module <module-name>
```

but after it created module i am getting below error and my meanjs app is not running except showing white page with console error

```
rror: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: MenusProvider <- Menus
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=MenusProvider%20%3C-%20Menus
return new ErrorConstructor(message);
```

i am using below version of generator

```
-- generator-meanjs@0.4.4
```

can anyone tel me what would be error.
my module name is customer

Answer (score 8):

in client\config\customers.cliuent.config.js  reemplace  this line:

```
menuConfig.$inject = ['menuService'];
```

with this:

```
menuConfig.$inject = ['Menus'];
```

Answer (score 3):

in client\config\customers.cliuent.config.js the yo package references the menuService as Menu.  change the references to the correct object name and it will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This common problem is caused due to 2 reasons:-

1- The bower.json has not been updated properly, for this use-->>

$ bower update

2- As most devs have already mentioned verify if the in the source folder(eg:src)-->>

```
src/module/(your crud module filename)/client/config/codes.client.config
```

change the value of

menuConfig.$inject = ['menuService'];

to

menuConfig.$inject = ['Menus'];

Tried and tested .. so if you still face issue please share the error message.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a new CRUD module to the default template the name of the menu is usually 'topbar' not 'Menus'. Try that and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered with the same issue. You should replace `Menus` with `menuService` in `customers.client.config.js`. So it will be like:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('customers')
    .run(menuConfig);

  menuConfig.$inject = ['menuService'];

  function menuConfig(menuService) {
    // Set top bar menu items
    menuService.addMenuItem('topbar', {
      title: 'Customers',
      state: 'customers',
      type: 'dropdown',
      roles: ['*']
    });

    // Add the dropdown list item
    menuService.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'customers', {
      title: 'List Customers',
      state: 'customers.list'
    });

    // Add the dropdown create item
    menuService.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'customers', {
      title: 'Create Customer',
      state: 'customers.create',
      roles: ['user']
    });
  }
}());
```